# Derivation of formula for sample size of finite population

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sample-size, finite-population

I found [here](http://www.surveysystem.com/sample-size-formula.htm) the formula for computing the sample size $n$ of a finite population $N$
$$
n = \frac{n_\infty}{1 + \frac{n_\infty - 1}{N}}
$$
where the sample size for an infinite population $n_\infty$ is given as
$$
n_\infty = \frac{z^2 p(1-p)}{c^2}
$$
with the the z-score $z$, the confidence interval $c$ and $p$ being the proportion of the population picking a specific choice. However I found no derivation of this formula. Can someone give a mathematical derivation of this formula?

Comment: The proof is a few pages. See Cochran, 1973, page 73.

Comment: @StatsStudent Do you have a link to some online resource with the proof, too?

Comment: Sorry.  I don't.  The Cochran books is considered the "bible" of sampling.  You should find it in any academic library.

Comment: link for Cochran 1977: https://archive.org/download/Cochran1977SamplingTechniques_201703/Cochran_1977_Sampling%20Techniques.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly a pretty complete derivation was given at math.stackexchange.com at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1357604/27609.

Another derivation can be found online [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025210819/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/264).